# Can I pass unpacking object as parameter in Javascript or JSX?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

```
var data = [
    {author: 'foo', comment: 'nice'},
    {author: 'bar', comment: 'wow'}
];

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var CommentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
            return (
                <Comment author={comment.author} comment={comment.comment}>
                </Comment>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div className="comment-box">
                {CommentNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Comment = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="comment-box comment">
                <h2 className="comment-author">
                    {this.props.author}
                </h2>
                {this.props.comment}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<CommentBox data={data}/>, document.getElementById("example"));
```

In the piece of code, I just pass the parameter to `Comment` using `data`. Since `data` is a `object`, which similar to Python's `dict`. So I'm wondering, can I just pass `data` as the unpacking `object`? Like using `**` is Python:

```
>>> def show(**kwargs):
...     return kwargs
... 
>>> items = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> print(show(**items))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Looks like data is an array and this.props.data.map is unpacking the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @AlexPalcuie answers above you can use [object spread](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html#spread-attributes) to accomplish exactly what python `**` operators do.

So this is equivalent to your code above:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var CommentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
            return (
                <Comment {...comment}>
                </Comment>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div className="comment-box">
                {CommentNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [spread attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html#spread-attributes) syntax.